# Add multiple columns to multiple data tables (frame) at the same time

Tags: r

I have a couple of tables with identical column names but different row sizes.
some of the columns are Dates and I would need to extract the year, months, day from them as factor and as numeric values and create within every table those new  columns.
What I need is a function which creates this faster than manually addad as in the example below.

```
 StartDate <- seq(as.Date("2014-01-19"), length = 20, by ="days")
 EndDate <- seq(as.Date("2015-01-19"), length = 20, by ="days")
 dt1 <- data.frame(x = sample(1:20, 20, TRUE), y = sample(1:20, 20, TRUE), StartDate, EndDate )
 setDT(dt1)

 StartDate <- seq(as.Date("2014-01-19"), length = 25, by ="days")
 EndDate <- seq(as.Date("2015-01-19"), length = 25, by ="days")
 dt2 <- data.frame(x = sample(1:40, 25, TRUE),  y = sample(1:40, 25, TRUE), StartDate, EndDate )
 setDT(dt2)

 StartDate <- seq(as.Date("2014-01-19"), length = 30, by ="days")
 EndDate <- seq(as.Date("2015-01-19"), length = 30, by ="days")
 dt3 <- data.frame(x = sample(1:40, 30, TRUE),  y = sample(1:40, 30, TRUE), StartDate, EndDate )
 setDT(dt3)
```

My manual solution:

```
 dt1[,   year  := as.factor(year(EndDate)), by = year(EndDate)] 
 dt1[,   year_num  := year(EndDate), by = year(EndDate)] 
 dt1[,   months := as.factor(month(EndDate)), by = month(EndDate)] 
 dt1[,   months_num := month(EndDate), by = month(EndDate)] 
 dt1[,   days  := x] 
 dt1[,   weekday := weekdays(EndDate), by = weekdays(EndDate)] 

 dt2 .....
 dt3 .....
```

I learned I would need to get all the datasets in a list with mget, then use lapply to loop over the list elements but I got some errors. Not sure how to make it.
Any help on this?
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on the right track. You need to get all the data in a list and iterate over it through `lapply`. However, I don't think the operations that you want to perform need to be grouped by month, year or week. You can perform them directly on each data table.

```
library(data.table)

list_data <- mget(paste0('dt', 1:3))
list_data <- lapply(list_data, function(x) {
  x[,   c('year', 'year_num', 'months', 'months_num', 'days', 'weekday') := 
        list(as.factor(year(EndDate)), year(EndDate), as.factor(month(EndDate)), 
             month(EndDate), x, weekdays(EndDate))] 
})
```